# Refreshing DNS after changing s3 bucket target IP address

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have an EC2 instance with a local port 8501 hosting a website app.py.

To give access to public, I have created an S3 bucket pointing to ipaddress:port in the properties dialogue and used Route53 to point to s3 bucket.

However, when I updated my EC2 instance the IP address changed. I updated S3 target and it works for all new users, but whoever had used my website before is being redirected to old ip address.

Is it possible to point it to new IP address for old users as well without asking them to clear cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, there are better ways to achieve what you need.

1. Assign Elastic IP (EIP) to the instance. Elastic IP won't change if you reboot or even stop and then start your instance. If you replace the instance with another one you can just reassign the EIP to the new instance.
2. Launch an Application Load Balancer (ALB) and attach your instance to it. ALB will take care of routing the traffic to the instance no matter what IP it has. The instance doesn't even have to have a public IP, internal IP will suffice.
3. Consider using Elastic Beanstalk. This service will span EC2 instances and load balancer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you've changed the IP address in a frontend asset or html file (which you will have because they're S3 objects) then the asset is likely cached for some users. The length of the caching can be observed by inspecting the [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) returned of the asset in question.

Regarding preventions for the future, avoid "hard coding" assets that you have no control over. Ultimately an IP can change (you can [attach an elastic IP address](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) to prevent this) if you user EC2, you might want to change this in the future which means that multiple hosts are used or you go with another service which again would require changing this in your code.

Instead you should create a DNS hostname for the host that is included in your assets, as this DNS hostname is far less likely to change (unless you decide to do it yourself). Once you create an A record and assigned it to your EC2 instances IP you should update your assets, this process will only need to be done once.

If in the future you decide to change the target(s) you simply update the DNS hostname to point at the other service instead. This requires no changes to the assets themselves, which means that once the DNS cache would clear it would target your new service.